# How to generate a list of all alphabets (UpperCase) in dart?

Tags: dart

Output expected from program

```
List<String> alphabets = [  "A",  "B",  "C",  "D",  "E",  "F",  "G",  "H",  "I",  "J",  "K",  "L",  "M",  "N",  "O",  "P",  "Q",  "R",  "S",  "T",  "U",  "V",  "W",  "X",  "Y",  "Z"  ];
```

Comment: Why is the example you give *not* a valid and good-enough solution? It satisfies that it contains the strings of all upper-case (ASCII) letters. Being more convoluted about computing that list doesn't seem warranted. So why do you want something else?
(Also, why do you *need* a list of the upper-case letters. Anything you can do with that seems like it can be done at least as well with a string or a custom tailored predicate).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is my single line answer

```
List.generate(26, (index) => print(String.fromCharCode(index+65)));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `List.generate()` to generate a list of desired type.
The first parameter is the length of the desired list, which is the distance between Z to A character or simply 26. The second parameter is the function that map each index to your desired character.

```
var aCode = 'A'.codeUnitAt(0);
var zCode = 'Z'.codeUnitAt(0);
List<String> alphabets = List<String>.generate(
    zCode - aCode + 1,
    (index) => String.fromCharCode(aCode + index),
  );
```

Take a look at the [List.generate](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.2/dart-core/List/List.generate.html) constructor of the `List` class.

Answer (score 5):

The following program gives the desired output

```
void main() {
  List<String> alphabets=[];
  for(int i=65; i<=90; i++){
    alphabets.add(String.fromCharCode(i));
  }
  print(alphabets);
}
```

About `String.fromCharCode` [read here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/String/String.fromCharCode.html)

Comment: A shorter version would be `var letters = [for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) String.fromCharCode(i)];`. Or `var lettes = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");`.